# What does android:isScrollContainer do?

Tags: android, view, scroll

Does anyone know what `android:isScrollCOntainer = (boolean)` or `$(View).setScrollContainer(boolean)` do?

At first I thought this would be the answer to set a View inside a ScrollView NOT to scroll with ScrollView, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

On Android Developers it says,

> "Set this if the view will serve as a scrolling container, meaning that it can be resized to shrink its overall window so that there will be space for an input method. "

Can anyone kindly explain what this description means?
What is a scrolling container in this case?
What kind of input method is available?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A scrolling container is one where the size of the container is independent of it's content.
For instance you can make a `ScrollView` or `ListView` of height 100 pixels, but you can fit as much content in as you want. Similarly regardless of the size of the content in the view, you can set the size the of the View to whatever you'd like.

If a container is scrollable, then Android knows it can shrink the size of the container without rendering parts of the content of the container inaccessible (since the user can just scroll down to see things not on screen). It uses this for when the SoftKeyboard is opened - if a container is scrollable it will shrink it as much as possible in an attempt to keep all of the elements on screen.

So `ScrollView`, `ListView`, `GridView` etc are all examples of scrolling containers.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking in to the same thing and I am not sure exactly what it means either. The input method is however the soft keyboard. Changing it affects how the views resize when an edittext is clicked and the keyboard pops up. Look in to android:windowSoftInputMode for more information.

I hope this was at least a little bit helpful!

Comment: I was able to avoid my bottom row of buttons getting pushed up by the soft keyboard by setting android:isScrollContainer="false" on the ScrollView above the buttons.