# Soft keyboard lifts tabhost Upwards

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-view, android-softkeyboard

My TabHost shifts upwards when soft keyboard opens by tapping `EditText`

**ScreenShot**

[image: Tab above soft keyboard]

**What I have done**

- For each activity I am using `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` to hide Soft Keyboard

**What I have tried**

- Included `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` for Activity in Manifest File

I have already gone through many accepted question however `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize` is not working in my case. Please suggest how to cop up with the situation.

**Edit**

**tabhost.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#333333" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_logo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_background"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Search for name"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/registrationLayout"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: put  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in your TabHost.

Comment: Edit: Layout.xml is added

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution.

- We must use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` however if the layout consist any `ScrollView` then `ScrollView` must have `android:isScrollContainer="false"` property.
- For more details Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308247/what-does-androidisscrollcontainer-do)

Answer (score 2):

```
  <activity
        android:name="Your activity name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait/Landscape"
        **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"** >
```