# Scrollview inside a layoutscreen viewpager doesnt scroll when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

my activity layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CaretmedicinechrActivity">


    <com.badoualy.stepperindicator.StepperIndicator
        android:id="@+id/stepper_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:stpi_labels="@array/stepLabels"
        app:stpi_indicatorColor="@color/Green"
        app:stpi_lineColor="@color/Blue"
        app:stpi_lineDoneColor="@color/Green"
        app:stpi_circleColor="@color/Blue"
        app:stpi_lineStrokeWidth="4dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stepper_indicator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

my screens that have multiple edittext

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout1ws"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4ws"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/medicinames"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editmdname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />


                </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout1ws"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/medicintype"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnertype"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/mdcinetype" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thbtnlayout"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/unit"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerunit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/mdcineunit" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thbtnlayout2"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView81"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/medicindosage"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editdosage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thbtnlayout3"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView82"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/medicinsession"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnersession"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/mdcinesessn" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thbtnlayout4"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/beforemeal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/afteremeal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup1"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView83"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editdesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thbtnlayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thbtnlayout5"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView812"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/medicinetimesday"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editntimed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is when the edittext gets focus, the keyboard overlaps the edittext area, rather than the scrollview causing the content to scroll.

I expect the fragment to handle keyboard shown and scrollview to fit the keyboard on the screen.

I already try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but this will scroll whole activity screen

Comment: Maybe this will help because i have a similar view with multiple edittext, first make the height "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content", and one more thing i did was set "isScrollContainer" as false.

Comment: `set "isScrollContainer" as false`  not work can you please describe your answer

Comment: checkout this answer for explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308247/what-does-androidisscrollcontainer-do)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in you manifest file. Under activity you are working on

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

For example, If you are working on main activity it should look like this..

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for screen that have multiple edittext make root view as `scrollView` not `RelativeLayout` 
and put flag in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`